# How to make pagination with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, api, pagination

i have a controller and i want to make pagination with 5 records per page. How can i do it with Nodejs i really need help.

```
const getPagination = (page, size) => {
const limit = size ? +size : 5; // Fetch 5 records
const offset = page ? page * limit : 0;// Start from page 0
    return { limit, offset };
};

// Find all car with condition and how can i add pagination ?
export function findAllCar( req, res){
    const name = req.query.name;
    const color = req.query.color;
    const brand = req.query.brand;
    var condition = name ? { 
        name: { [Op.iLike]: `%${name}%` },  
        color: { [Op.iLike]: `%${color}%` },
        brand: { [Op.iLike]: `%${brand}%` }, 
    } : null;
    Car.findAll({ where: condition })
      .then(data => {
        res.send(data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
          message:
            err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving CARS."
        });
      });
}
```

Comment: which orm are you using sequlize or any other?

Comment: i use sequelize and postgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
model.findAll({
  limit: 5,
  offset: 0,
  where: {}, // conditions
});
```

Comment: it might not be the best but thanks for your help